# Rotate only part of the vertices?

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

I'm adding an OpenGL renderer to my 2D game engine and I want to know whether there is a way to apply an mvp matrix only to part of the vertices in a single draw call?

I'm planning to group draw calls by textures so I'll pass a buffer of many vertices and texcoords, now I want to apply different rotation angles to different quads. Is there a way to accomplish it in the shader or should I give up on the mvp matrix in the shader and perform the same thing using the cpu?

**EDIT:** What about adding 3 float attributes (rotation and rot_center.xy) per vertex?

what's better performance

(1) doing CPU rotation?

(2) providing 3 more floats per vertex

(3) separating draw calls?

Is there any other option?

Comment: Use the cpu, I expect, as just changing specific vertices is probably beyond what shaders do.

Comment: It will be impossible to answer 'what is the better performance'. It will depend on the speed of your cpu, the speed of your gpu, the number of vertices, the number of draw calls, and etc etc. Just pick one that works for you, and if you find it to be too slow, then try some other methods and profile which is the best.

Comment: I'll profile the code obviously, but I am more interested to know whether there are other and better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility:

1. Do the rotation in the vertex shader. Pass in the information (angle?) needed to create the rotation matrix as a vertex attribute.
2. Pass in a vertex attribute (ubyte) that is effectively a per-vertex boolean flag. Rotation in #1 will be executed only if the bool is set.

Not sure if the above will work for you from a performance/storage perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, while it is a good thing to group draw calls for many different performance reasons, changing your code to satisfy a basic requirement as rotation is not a good idea.

Drawing batching is a good thing but, if you are forced to keep an additional attribute (because you cannot do it with uniforms for sure, you wouldn't have the information of the single entity) it is not worth.

An additional attribute means much more memory bandwidth usage that usually is the main killing factor for performances on nowadays systems.

Drawing batching, on the other side, is important but not always critical, it depends on many factors such as:

1. the GPU OpenGL driver optimization
2. The GPU tiles configuration
3. The number of shapes/draw calls we are talking about (if you have 20 quads on the screen, why should you bother of batching? :) )

In other words, often it is much more convenient to drop extreme batching in favor of easiness/main tenability and avoid fancy solutions for simple requirements as rotation.

I hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Use two different objects, that is all!

There is no other workaround for rotation of part of object

Example:

A game with a tank, where you want to rotate turret and remaining-body separately. Like in your case here these two are treated as separate objects.